# How to find specific attribute by matching the element XML using Python?

Tags: python, xml, powershell, attributes, match

I would like to find the specific attribute by matching the element from XML file. Here my XML looks like.

```
<Data>
     <family no="1309" description="date">
          <desc name="rt1" code="10.010" />
               <disk name="xsfdf" ver="9.11" />
               <disk name="jhgjt" ver="sryj" />
          </desc>
          <desc name="rt2" code="2210.9" />
               <disk name="kury" ver="45.11" />
               <disk name="jyd" ver="liud" />
          </desc>
     </family>
     <family no="2006" description="date">
          <desc name="rt3" code="16450.010" />
               <disk name="ytdts" ver="9.11" />
               <disk name="sj" ver="8346" />
          </desc>
          <desc name="rt5" code="165460.9" />
               <disk name="kgd" ver="65.11" />
               <disk name="asdr" ver="97.986" />
          </desc>
     </family>
</Data>
```

I would like to get the value of `name` by matching the value  of `code="10.010"`. In powershell I tried it like this:

```
$Code = "10.010"
$FileName = ($ReadXML.Data.family.desc | Where-Object {$_.code -like "*$Code*"}).disk.name
Write-Host "$FileName"
```

Anyone can help me please how to do it in Python. Really appreciate the help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using xpath in this case:

```
$xml = [xml]'<Data>
     <family no="1309" description="date">
          <desc name="rt1" code="10.010" >
               <disk name="xsfdf" ver="9.11" />
               <disk name="jhgjt" ver="sryj" />
          </desc>
          <desc name="rt2" code="2210.9" >
               <disk name="kury" ver="45.11" />
               <disk name="jyd" ver="liud" />
          </desc>
     </family>
     <family no="2006" description="date">
          <desc name="rt3" code="16450.010" >
               <disk name="ytdts" ver="9.11" />
               <disk name="sj" ver="8346" />
          </desc>
          <desc name="rt5" code="165460.9" >
               <disk name="kgd" ver="65.11" />
               <disk name="asdr" ver="97.986" />
          </desc>
     </family>
</Data>'
#note that the xml in your question is not well formed; I fixed it above

$target = $xml | Select-Xml ".//desc[@code='10.010']/@name"
echo $target.ToString()
```

or using python:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(data)
target = doc.xpath(".//desc[@code='10.010']/@name")[0]
print(target)
```

Output:

```
rt1
```

EDIT:

or

```
target = doc.xpath(".//desc[@code='10.010']/disk/@name")[0]
print(target)
```

to get

```
xsfdf
```

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciated. But my expectation using Python not Powershell. @Jack Fleeting

Comment: @SBR Sorry; your code was in ps - i missed the python reference at the end. See edit.

Comment: hi @Jack. Thank you! But I need to get the value of  `<disk name="xsfdf"` name of the disk not the name of the desc